# MySQL getting crashed frequently

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu

MySQL server is getting crashed again again, I'm not getting how to fix this issue:
I'm using mysql for wordpress.

System status when crashed:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit-hit) since Tue 2022-09-27 06:48:56 UTC; 35min ago
  Process: 5801 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 5800 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=killed, signal=KILL)
  Process: 5792 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 5800 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
```

After starting server:

```
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-09-27 07:31:15 UTC; 3min 12s ago
  Process: 6492 ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 6483 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 6491 (mysqld)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           └─6491 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 2 hours UPTIME, if possible
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
H) SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.